# SSRS - How to get sum of values using reportitems!textbox1.value and reset to 0 for every group created in report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

How can I get sum of values using `reportitems!textbox1.value` and reset to `0` for every group created in report?

Comment: Look into using the RunningTotal function that is built into SSRS.

Comment: I'd be surprised if putting the expression =SUM(reportitems!textbox1.value) in a cell within the grouping did not do this.  Screenshots?

Comment: You cannot aggregate at Reportitem level